# Sorting Map using Comparator

Tags: java, sorting, dictionary, comparator

I'm trying `Comparator` to implement a sort in `TreeMap` according to a sequence.

```
    final String sequence="People,Object,Environment,Message,Service";
Comparator<String> comparator = new Comparator<String>() {
             @Override
             public int compare(String key1, String key2) {
                 int returned = sequence.indexOf(key1) - sequence.indexOf(key2);

                 if (returned == 0 && !key1.contains(key2))
                     returned = -1;

                 return returned;

             }
         };
List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>();
          Map<String,String> lhm = new TreeMap<String,String>(comparator);
       // Put elements to the map
          lhm.put("Object", "biu");
          lhm.put("Message", "nuios");
          lhm.put("Service", "sdfe");
          lhm.put("People", "dfdfh");
          lhm.put("Environment", "qwe");
          lhm.put("Other", "names");
          lhm.put("Elements", "ioup");          
          lhm.put("Rand", "uiy");
for(Entry<String, String> entry : lhm.entrySet()) {
                System.out.println(entry.getKey());
            }
```

The Output which I'm getting here is

```
Rand
Elements
Other
People
Object
Environment
Message
Service
```

The Elements in treemap which equals the sequence are ordered correctly but other elements which are not following the sequence should come after the sequence.My expectation is like following

```
People
Object
Environment
Message
Service
Rand
Elements
Other
```

How to implement this?

Suppose If I add some more words to the elements of my TreeMap means my Comparator doesn't even order the elements.Like this

```
lhm.put("Object IOn", "biu");
          lhm.put("Message dfb", "nuios");
          lhm.put("Serviceabc", "sdfe");
          lhm.put("Peoplexxx", "dfdfh");
          lhm.put("Environmentxxx", "qwe");
          lhm.put("Other", "names");
          lhm.put("Elements", "ioup");          
          lhm.put("Rand", "uiy");
```

My Output become

```
Rand
Elements
Other
Environmentxxx
Peoplexxx
Serviceabc
Message dfb
Object IOn
```

Somebody help me to rewrite my Comparator to fix this problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/109383/how-to-sort-a-mapkey-value-on-the-values-in-java

Comment: @JNL Beware the top-voted answer on that post.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some simple code that should to the task.

```
import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class FixedOrderComparator implements Comparator<String> {

  private final Map<String, Integer> index = new HashMap<>();

  public FixedOrderComparator(String elements) {
    String[] split = elements.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
      index.put(split[i], i);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public int compare(String left, String right) {
    Integer rankLeft = index.get(left);
    Integer rankRight = index.get(right);
    if (rankLeft != null && rankRight != null) {
      return rankLeft.compareTo(rankRight);
    }
    if (rankLeft == null && rankRight == null) {
      return left.compareTo(right);
    }
    return Boolean.compare(rankLeft == null, rankRight == null);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to correct your logic used in the comparator.

```
  final String sequence="People,Object,Environment,Message,Service";
  System.out.println(sequence.indexOf("People"));  // 0
  System.out.println(sequence.indexOf("Object"));  // 7
  System.out.println(sequence.indexOf("Message"));  // 26
  System.out.println(sequence.indexOf("Environment")); // 14
```

`.indexOf(key1)` returns the index of the `first character of the String` and not the `String`.

```
 int returned = sequence.indexOf(key1) - sequence.indexOf(key2);
 if(returned < 0){ 
    // then it is sorted; 
    return 1;
 }
 else{ return -1; }
```

Comment: Is there a way to compare whole string?

Comment: @VigneshVino What do you mean by compare the whole String? System.out.println(sequence.contains("Object")); will give you true or false.

Comment: Can you please explain more about my problem in your answer?