# Sorting without Class source code

Tags: java

Interviewer question in one of my interviews.

> We have `Employee` class with `id`, `firstName`, and `lastName` fields and getters and setters of these fields. We do not have source code of this class, it is in JAR. We are using `Employee` instances as the key in `TreeMap`. Now we want to sort this `TreeMap` based on the `Employee` `id` field.

I know we can use `Comparable` interface to sort but how can we use it if we do not have the source code?

Comment: You can use Comparator.

Comment: Why would source code be relevant at all?

Comment: Use Comparator, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720800/sorting-map-using-comparator

Comment: @lexicore The fact that you don't have source code prevents you from making the class implement [`Comparable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html). They want the alternative, i.e. for answer to be that you can give a [**`Comparator`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) on the [`TreeMap` constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html#%3Cinit%3E(java.util.Comparator)). It's a test to see how familiar you are with `TreeMap`, one of the more common classes in the Java Runtime Library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sorting Map using Comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18720800/sorting-map-using-comparator)

Comment: @Andreas You can't make third-party class implement `Comparable` independent of whether source code is available or not. So I still don't see how source code availability is relevant.

Comment: @contrapost Of course it is a duplicate but only for those who already know :) If anyone does not know about the existence of the `Comparator` the question is *different*. It should stay here.

Answer (score 0):

Based on [Andreas comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50128774/sorting-without-class-source-code#comment87275453_50128774) :

Since you does not have the source code, you can't use the interface comparable. And that's the goal of your interviewer to make you use an alternative. This alternative is to use a [Comparator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html).

I'll let you search how to use it ([here an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12947088/java-treemap-comparator))

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

1. Subclass `Employee` and have the derived class implement `Comparable<...>`
2. Write a `Comparator<Employee>` and pass it as a parameter to the constructor of `TreeMap`

The first one is more trouble than it's worth, because you're dealing with a different class. So let's see about using a `Comparator`.

```
final Comparator<Employee> employeeComparator = Comparator
        .comparing(Employee::getLastName)
        .thenComparing(Employee::getFirstName);
final SortedMap<Employee, String> map = new TreeMap<>(employeeComparator);
```

This defines the comparator as a Java 8 lambda that first compares the last name and then the first name.